# Can't include Objective C Files into Project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, import, ssziparchive

I want to include an Objective-C project (https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) into my Swift Project so that I can include the SSZipArchive into my project. I need this so I can unzip a file. As included in the instructions on the Github, I included the folder `minizip`, `SSZipArchive.h`, and `SSZipArchive.m` into my project. I have also created a bridging header where I included the following import into my project `#import "SSZipArchive.h"`. However, when I try to type SSZipArchive on Xcode, the autocomplete doesn't occur, leading me to believe that SSZipArchive isn't included properly in my project. Any ideas on how to do so? I have already looked at numerous links on how to include Objective-C projects into Swift and I have found that I simply need to include the corresponding header files for my project to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you haven't set bridging header path properly. It's a very common problem, but easy one to fix.
Go to the Project Settings -> Build Settings -> Search, and search for `bridg`, and under Objective-C Bridging Header set the path of your bridging header file (carefully inspect it's path in Finder first, since it may be in some sub-directory of your project).

Also make sure that all your included header files have target of your application. To check if they have, click on the header file, open up Utilities from the right side and under Target Membership, make sure the first target is checked.